# Static directory / subsite not managed by EE

Tags: url, subdomain

I have a full EE2 site at domain.com. The problem I am running into is, I would like to have a separate non-EE managed site at something.domain.com and/or domain.com/something. It seems as though EE2 always takes over the URI, and my knowledge of .htaccess re-writing is limited. Is there a simple way to specify a directory that EE2 should not have control over?

Current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    AddType video/webm .webm

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~domain/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you post your current .htaccess file contents?

Comment: @DerekHogue see edit.

Comment: "something.domain.com" and "domain.com/something" are very different beasts. Which are you trying to set up exactly?

Answer (score 1):

htaccess can be directory specific so I'd be inclined to add a separate htaccess file for that directory and have

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current **.htaccess** file indicates that any files or directories actually found on the server will be served as-is. So if you throw some static files (or even another application) in a folder called **/foo**, it should load without that request being redirected through EE's controller.

These lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Are telling the server to only execute this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~domain/index.php/$1 [L]
```

If the request is not an actual file or folder on the server.

For a subdomain, you'd want to look at your hosting control panel to set that up, and likely point it to a different webspace altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a subdomain for a different directory on the server to run a different set of content, then it seems to me you should be working on your virtual host settings and not .htaccess.  I read your question to mean that you have an EE site at domain.com and you want a different site at subdomain.domain.com.  That is something you would set up in virtual host settings.  Requests to subdomain.domain.com should go into one virtual host and requests for domain.com should go in another.  I would guess that your virtual host config currently looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
DocumentRoot /path/to/document/root
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

that ServerAlias is grabbing all traffic to all subdomains of domain.com, but most probably if you added another virtual host listening on 80 with ServerName subdomain.domain.com and a DocumentRoot pointing to wherever you want to put your files for this other site, your subdomain will now work for these other files.

If you want to have them in a subfolder, then the rewrite rule should not be touching them if the request if for a directory or filename that actually exists on the server.  Your rewrite rule says only rewrite if this request is not an image file, is not a request for an actual existing filename, and is not a request for an actual existing directory.  So if you have a folder in Document Root named /subfolder and in subfolder you have a file called index.html them a request to domain.com/subfolder/index.html really should load the file that is actually there.

Comment: someone asked me a question off this site about this answer, but I'm not sure what the question was.  If this was you please clarify here and I'll answer, but I don't want to take the information off the site.

Comment: If you create a sub domain then your master htaccess file for your EE site will never impact on the sub domain. However, if you have a sub directory then the master htaccess will impact all the way unless there's another htaccess file in that directory.

Comment: Sounds to me like the OPs server is running cPanel or similar, which by default puts subdomains and addon domains in directories in the web root of the accounts primary domain.

Comment: Still, in the case of a subdomain I think the key would be to have a virtual host definition with a server name that covers that specific subdomain to stop the main virtual host from handling those requests.

Comment: Steven, I was saying that the .htaccess rule shouldn't touch them because of the rewriteCond not because they were in subdirectories.